# Auto.Arima() in R Forecast package behaving erratically

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, jri

I'm using R with the forecast version 5.4 plugin by Rob Hyndman.  It's a really nice package, but it seems to be acting oddly, predicting wildly different results for similar data.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the warning message generated at the end of the data here, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
     library(forecast)
     v <- vector("numeric")
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,115.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,115.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,115.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,117.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,117.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,117.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,113.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,112.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,120.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,119.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     series <- ts(v, frequency=12)
     series
  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1   0 115   0   0   0 115   0   0   0 115   0   0
2   0   0 117   0   0   0 117   0   0   0 117   0
3   0   0   0   0 113   0   0   0 112   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0 120   0   0   0 119   0   0   0
     a <- auto.arima(series)
     // Note there is no error

     v <- vector("numeric")
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,109.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,120.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,114.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,125.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,135.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,130.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,104.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,114.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,126.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,114.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     v <- append(v,0.0)
     series <- ts(v, frequency=12)
     a <- auto.arima(series)
Warning message:
In max(which(abs(testvec)          1e-08)) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
     series
  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1   0 109   0   0   0 120   0   0   0 114   0   0
2   0   0 125   0   0   0 135   0   0   0 130   0
3   0   0   0   0 104   0   0   0 114   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0 126   0   0   0 114   0   0   0
```

You can see that the data sets are almost identical, but the second throws a warning message.  If you copy and paste into R, you can see that the forecasts for the second are off as well.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

*** Update ***

Note that this example was put together after about a day of R experience and is simply logger text.  Using JRI (the Java interface to R), I came up with the following to simulate an ArrayList.  Early prototypes aren't always the prettiest.

```
            eval(re, "v <- vector(\"numeric\")");
            for (int i = 0; i < months.size(); i++) {
                eval(re, "v <- append(v," + months.get(i) + ")");
            }
```

Comment: Who taught you to create vectors by using append and only adding a single value each time?

Comment: Constructive criticism or pointers are appreciated.  Perhaps teaching the correct way to create vectors would have been more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your data again, inputted much more efficiently. Why use `append` statements???

```
library(forecast)
v1 <- ts(c(0, 115, 0, 0, 0, 115, 0, 0, 0, 115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 117, 0, 0, 
          0, 117, 0, 0, 0, 117, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 113, 0, 0, 0, 112, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 119, 0, 0, 0), frequency=12)
fit1 <- auto.arima(v1)
plot(forecast(fit1))

v2 <- ts(c(0, 109, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0, 
       0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0, 114, 0, 0, 
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126, 0, 0, 0, 114, 0, 0, 0), frequency=12)
fit2 <- auto.arima(v2)
plot(forecast(fit2))
```

The warning is coming up because `auto.arima` tries to fit a model that happens to have all estimated coefficients equal to zero. The next release of the forecast package (available at https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast) fixes this warning.

An ARIMA model is inappropriate for both of these time series in any case. Try to understand what is causing the zeros and non-zeros, and build a model that is appropriate to the data. For example, it might include two processes -- one for the time between non-zero values and one for the magnitude of the non-zero values.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I thought it was due to a setting being off.  Thank you for the correct way to create a vector as well.

Comment: Is the behavior of `auto.arima` in this situation documented? From the behavior shown in the answer, it looks like the forecast turns out to just be the average of the series carried forward, which would be fine. But I need to be confident in my understanding of how `auto.arima` works on unsuitable timeseries.